# How to scale area of distribution to number different than 1 with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am having some trouble scaling the distribution of two subgroups. I need to plot the distribution of two subgroups in two different plots. However, the total area is by default set to 1 whereas I would like to set a specific value.

How can I set the area manually to a specific value so that the sum of the area of the two distribution in the 2 different plots is equal to one?

I have tried to use `weight` but it does not seem to work:

```
x_dorsal <- ggplot() +
  stat_density(data = x_dorsal_17, aes(x = x),  weight = 0.6, geom = "line", position = "identity", size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-850, 850), breaks=seq(from = -850, to = 850, by = 850)) +
  theme_classic()

x_ventral <- ggplot() +
  stat_density(data = x_ventral_17, aes(x = x),  weight = 0.4, geom = "line", position = "identity", size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-850, 850), breaks=seq(from = -850, to = 850, by = 850)) +
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the y axis labels:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = \(lab) {lab / 2})
```